# Formula to use in Google sheets to count all cells containing specific texts

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a link to a sample spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcfqPxsnQGEVZKd2imM1WPYRvgbZBiEQ18mHVd3znjE/edit?usp=sharing

What I want to do is count all unique values in column C (ID) and all values in column A (initial email) in the month of November.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(Sample!C2:C,Sample!A2:A="Mon, Nov. 23, 2015 2PM"))
```

But it would only count one specific date in November so I would have to also count all the other dates and then total them. Is there a way for the formula to count all unique values in column C and count all values in Column A containing "*Nov*"?
To add to that, I also need to count all values in Column F (Response category), containing unique ID for the month of November.

Comment: I can't see your spreadsheet because you didn't allow others to view it. Click "Share" in upper right.

Comment: Also, the last sentence, with "containing unique ID for the month of November" is unclear.  You may want to explain what exactly those values should contain.

Comment: I just shared the link and I'm trying out the formula right now.

Comment: No, I still can't see it. Try opening the link in a private browser window, to see how it appears to me.

Comment: The link should finally be shared. I used the regexmatch but couldn't seem to get the right number. Please have a look at the 'statistics' tab.

Comment: @NormalHuman, as a follow up question, if I may, how do I do regexmatch for two criteria? E.g., in the spreadsheet I shared, how can I count all unique values for dates with "Nov" and "2015" in it?

Comment: Use the regular expression "Nov.*2015" instead of "Nov".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filted by [`regexmatch`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) instead of equality.

```
=countunique(filter(Sample!C2:C, regexmatch(Sample!A2:A, "Nov")))
```

Matching the regular expression "Nov" simply means containing "Nov" somewhere in the string.

Comment: I tried the "regexmatch" formula (please see "Statistics" tab) but couldn't get the right number. It should have been 12 but the formula counted only 9.

Comment: If I just do a pure 'countunique' on the Nov data, I get 9. It seems right to me. [Example here - listing unique and counting for just Nov](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ymSnNbcZyfw6S1m-NECzRhsfp6zMDbh7FHoTlgcB8M0/edit#gid=0&vpid=A1)

Comment: @Vee 9 is the correct number of unique values for all November dates. If you count unique values for each particular date separately, and then add, that's a different count. E.g., you can have 550 on Nov 3 and 550 on Nov 9. In a count for all of November, it's 1. Counting separately by dates and adding, it's 1+1 = 2.

Comment: @NormalHuman That makes sense to me now. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @TomWoodward Thanks for the response. You (and NormalHuman) both helped me.